# Flutter binary and Dart binary path problem

Tags: flutter

Currently in the process of installing everything related to Flutter (VS, VS Code, Extensions...) and went into a problem.

I am following this Help Document; but seem to have encountered a problem.

While doing Step 3 (Validating VS Code Setup), I type in "doctor" in VS Code Command Palette, and I see 2 errors in the output, saying that Flutter binary and Dart binary is not on my path.

It says "consider adding XXX to your path", but it didn't do anything when adding exactly this in the "Environment Variables Path" In my windows. Is that the path they're talking about ?
[image]

Tried adding directory they recommended me to add, to my Environment Variables, under the "Path" button, didn't change anything. Was that the right place to put this directory ?

Comment: Have you tried step 3 from this https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-install-flutter/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Start,save%20the%20changes.:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Start,the%20blow%20images:~:text=Open%20the%20Start,the%20blow%20images

Comment: Assuming you've [added the directories to your path](https://linuxhint.com/add-directory-to-path-environment-variables-windows/) correctly, you will have to close and re-open a terminal for the updated path to be read in. Try opening a new terminal or re-opening vscode and running the same command :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `dart-sdk` to `PATH` variable of `User Variables` and `System Variables` both, along with `flutter\bin` path.

So, your `flutter` path is:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\flutter\bin
```

Make sure you have added this above path to both `User Variables` and `System Variables`.

Now, add `dart-sdk` path which is inside `flutter\bin`, so it will be:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
```

Now, add this, above path to both `User Variables` and `System Variables`.

Now, try to run:

```
flutter doctor
```